# How to work with multistep form in react js with Nested FormArray using React Hook Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm new in react. Need help to create form with multiple nested field array like I have provide json, I have used react hook form for validation.
Facing issue to create dynamic setting,model array data form elements,
I need to create below Json on form submit

```
{
    "field_data": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "fields": [
                {
                    "name": "Field 1",
                    "config": {
                        "type": "Number",
                        "setting": {
                            "model": [
                                {
                                    "id": 7,
                                    "value": []
                                },
                                {
                                    "id": 6,
                                    "value": []
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "extra_info": {                           
                            "suffix": ""
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Field 2",
                    "config": {
                        "type": "Any",
                        "setting": {
                            "model": []
                        },
                        "extra_info": {
                           
                            "suffix": ""
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "name": "Field 3",
                    "config": {
                        "type": "Any",
                        "setting": {
                            "model": []
                        },
                        "extra_info": {
                            
                            "suffix": ""
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "name": "sacascasc"
}
```

In above json input will be "model" and "extra_info"
How to work with multiple nexted formarray

Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is your form type? textInput?

Comment: yes, user will add/ remove setting.model functionality